# Can't create ember record from console

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase

I've just started learning ember.js (v2.0.0), I was following [this page](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/creating-web-components-in-emberjs.html), and at one point, the tutorial instructs me to create 4 records from the chrome console. I do exactly as instructed, but nothing happens. No errors, warnings, nothing.

On the Ember Inspector, I'm doing this:
[image: Ember inspector image from the mentioned tutorial.]

On the console, after clicking ">$E" as mentioned in the image, I'm entering this:

```
$E.store.createRecord('customer', { name: 'John Smith', location: 'Boston', isSubscribed: false }).save()
$E.store.createRecord('customer', { name: 'Jenny Reed', location: 'New York', isSubscribed: false }).save()
$E.store.createRecord('customer', { name: 'Bill Crawford', location: 'Philadelphia', isSubscribed: true, subscriptionDate: new Date(), subscriptionDuration: 12 }).save()
$E.store.createRecord('customer', { name: 'Cathy Smith', location: 'Boston', isSubscribed: true, subscriptionDate: new Date(), subscriptionDuration: 6 }).save()
```

This is the screenshot after that.
[image: Screenshot from my Ember Inspector]

EDIT: The data tab shows "customer(0)", customer being the model, with no entries. Also, I thought I'll just log what's in $E, but, I can't. I'm not clear with how that works. And, I checked my firebase server too. Nothing there either. But that's ok I guess considering that EmberFire just synced my Ember-Data records to firebase, and the Ember-Data record was empty here.

If things went as expected, I should have had 4 records synced to my firebase server, but that's not what happened.

I have the Ember Inspector from Chrome Web Store installed.
Basically, I've followed the instructions exactly as described in the tutorial.

Hours of googling didn't help.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're typing into the console (exactly) so that your question is in one place?

Comment: @elithrar Thanks for the response, I've edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: Does the "Data" tab of the Ember Inspector show any records? My guess is that you're missing a terminating semi-colon `;` at the end of each line.

Comment: semicolon's are optional in javascript.

Comment: Not exactly optional [asi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) takes care of that

Comment: @elithrar The data tab shows the model "customer(0)", with no records in it.